# How to make a start menu with another frame in Java?

Tags: java, swing, menu, startmenu

So I'm making a game and It's working quite well, but I just need to have a start menu with 3 buttons. A Play, Instructions and Exit button. The problem is that I want it in a different frame than the game itself, if you press on Start the frame should switch to the game frame. Can someone help me with this?
This is a part of my code:

```
package frametest;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.util.Arrays;
import javax.swing.*;

public class FrameTest extends JFrame implements ActionListener {
    public JPanel createContentPane() {
        //Jpanels and stuff
    }

    public JPanel createMainMenu() {
        //Start menu JPanels and stuff
    }

    private static void createAndShowGUI() {
        JFrame.setDefaultLookAndFeelDecorated(true);
        JFrame frame = new JFrame("Poker Game");

        FrameTest demo = new FrameTest();
        frame.setContentPane(demo.createContentPane());

        frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);  
        frame.setSize(1080,640);
        frame.setVisible(false);

        JFrame menu = new JFrame("Poker Game");

        menu.setContentPane(demo.createMainMenu());

        menu.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);  
        menu.setSize(1080,640);
        menu.setVisible(true);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() { 
                createAndShowGUI();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: See [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9554657/418556)

Comment: What is the question?

Comment: Why don't use a modal `JDialog` to show the 3 buttons? If *Start* button is pressed then just dispose this dialog. [How to Use Modality in Dialogs](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/modality.html)

Answer (score 2):

You must have a setting `frame` class for your main function and essential for `frame` and you should have another class for game controlling and a class for menu.

You should get instant of game controller in `frame` and do the same in controller for menu then you can have separate `frame` that you want.

`please use interfaces to have a clean code`.